# Finding the strains from a 0, 90 rosette - Mohr's circle

Tags: material-science

I have used a strain rosette with two gauges at 0 and 90 degrees to find strain on a beam under force and an trying to plot Mohr's circle for the problem. As the gauges are at right angles finding the xx and yy strain is easy but I am lost about how to find the xy strain, which I need to plot the circle. How can I find xy from the xx and yy strain values?

Comment: Do you happen to have any additional information on the question? It seems that there isn't enough data from the rosette to give up much idea what other strains there. We may know the strains $\epsilon_{xx}$ and $\epsilon_{yy}$, but we cannot tell, from the data provided, if they are even principle strains or not. (Usually a three-gauge rosette has enough data to plot the circle).

Comment: The gauges are set up in such a way that I think they are the principle strains.

Comment: If that's the case, then the xy strain, $\gamma_{xy} = 0$, because that's due to the definition of the principle strain. You measure the principle strains whenever no shear strains are measured for that particular orientation.

Comment: Would you also happen to have a diagram of the beam and rosette, just so I'm visualising this right?

Comment: I don't actually have a diagram but I've spoken to a few other people and what you've said makes a lot of sense. Thanks very much!